# How to add CommandParameter to textblock

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to add a little functionality to wpf control via class presented below.

```
namespace ATCheckerView
{
    public class AttachedMouseBinding
    {
        public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject obj, Object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static Object GetCommandParameter(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCommandParameter(DependencyObject obj, Object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AttachedMouseBinding),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CommandChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(AttachedMouseBinding),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CommandParameterChanged));

        private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
            var command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            if (command == null) return;
            var inputBinding = new InputBinding(command, new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftDoubleClick));
            fe.InputBindings.Add(inputBinding);
        }

        private static void CommandParameterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
            // var parameter = e.NewValue as Object;
        }
    }
}
```

I used it like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Tag="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext}"
           Text="{Binding Path=path, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           ContextMenu="{StaticResource SchemeContextMenu}"
           local:AttachedMouseBinding.Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.vclient.OpenInViewer}"
           local:AttachedMouseBinding.CommandParameter="{Binding}">
</TextBlock>
```

My question is: as now send CommandParameter to the command

UPD:
Igor's variant with my changes:


`private static void OnMouseLeftClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var me = e as MouseButtonEventArgs;
            if (me != null && me.ClickCount != 2) return;`

`FrameworkElement control = sender as FrameworkElement;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        if (command.CanExecute(commandParameter))
            command.Execute(commandParameter);
    }`

Comment: Where `Command.Execute(object)` supposed to be called? Since it is the only place where command parameter required the answer directly depends on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you triying fired command on mouseleft click?

Try this:

```
public static class AttachedMouseBinding
{


    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AttachedMouseBinding), new UIPropertyMetadata(CommandChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(AttachedMouseBinding), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target, object value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
    public static object GetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return target.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement control = target as FrameworkElement;
        if (control != null)
        {
            if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
            {
                control.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftClick;
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
            {
                control.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftClick;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnMouseLeftClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement control = sender as FrameworkElement;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        if (command.CanExecute(commandParameter))
            command.Execute(commandParameter);
    }


}
```

Comment: ok, it worked for me. But I would like to execute command on double click on the left mouse. I got this in the folowing way(added to question), it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

Modify xaml

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Tag="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext}"
           Text="{Binding Path=path, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           ContextMenu="{StaticResource SchemeContextMenu}">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
          <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.vclient.OpenInViewer}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```